# How do PyId_ variables resolve in CPython?

Tags: python, cpython, python-internals

I've seen usages for `PyId_` variables all around the CPython source code. I couldn't trace back to the definition of any of them.

Examples include `PyId___name__` and others.

Who or what resolves them into strings? I've seen a C-analyzer with `known.csv` file on the CPython source, listing most of them (but not all). Not sure if it's relevant.

Comment: These are basically "interned strings"; a way of ensuring that a string literal exists only once in memory, despite multiple uses in the source code (which the C language itself does not guarantee).  The actual definitions are performed by a macro expansion that looks like `_Py_IDENTIFIER(__name__);`; in this case being located in Objects/moduleobject.c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jasonharper said, `PyId_` variables are defined using [`_Py_IDENTIFIER`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Include/cpython/object.h#L46), usually found at the top of the source files.

Snippet:

```
#define _Py_IDENTIFIER(varname) _Py_static_string(PyId_##varname, #varname)
```

`_Py_IDENTIFIER` works using [stringizing and token-parsing](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/and-operators-in-c/) operators which allow you to define new variables programmatically.

The string values are then interned for better memory efficiency.